# Meaning of tcpdump P direction

Tags: linux-networking, bridge, tcpdump

The situation is a VM running under kvm/libvirt/qemu (`10.202.7.128`) pinging another hardware-based system (`10.202.7.4`) via the hypervisor's bridge.  Everything works OK but `'tcpdump -neli any icmp and host 10.202.7.128'` shows three entries per request:

```
14:42:39.921785 P 52:54:00:14:71:1b 
ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 2485, seq 1, length 64
```

The second entry is identical except the `P` is replaced with `"Out"`, the third entry is identical to the first.  This is followed by three replies from the same MAC address for `10.202.7.4` with the only difference being the `P`, `Out`, `P` sequence.

Why are there three entries per ping and what does the `P` in the direction mean?  I've searched the web in vain unless I searched for the wrong thing.

#### Update:

Based on Zoredache's answer I clanged the interface specification to the three involved: `vnet5` (the guest VM's NIC on the hypervisor), `br0` (the hypervisor's bridge) and `eno1` (the physical NIC identified as the bridge port for the bridge) and got one request/reply for each ping when testing each interface so I'm (wildly) guessing that's the reason for the three entries using "any".  I'm still baffled about the `P` and sequence of `P`, `Out`, `P.`
Any insight?

**Further update** (and I want to thank Anton for his research, much appreciated.)

Ran test again with four tcpdump specifications, all `'-neli <interface> icmp and host 10.202.7.128'` with interfaces `vnet5`, `br0`, `eno1` and "`any`".  Noted timestamps to determine what "`any`" entry matched the individual interface entries.

"Any" results (`vnet5/10.202.7.128` is `52:54:00:a2:bd:48`, `10.202.7.4` is `b0:00:b4:02:93:6e`)

```
00:06:57.775050   P 52:54:00:a2:bd:48 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775074 Out 52:54:00:a2:bd:48 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775050   P 52:54:00:a2:bd:48 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775940   P b0:00:b4:02:93:6e ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.4 > 10.202.7.128: ICMP echo reply, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775956 Out b0:00:b4:02:93:6e ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.4 > 10.202.7.128: ICMP echo reply, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775940   P b0:00:b4:02:93:6e ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 10.202.7.4 > 10.202.7.128: ICMP echo reply, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
```

vnet5 results

```
00:06:57.775050 52:54:00:a2:bd:48 > b0:00:b4:02:93:6e, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775956 b0:00:b4:02:93:6e > 52:54:00:a2:bd:48, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.202.7.4 > 10.202.7.128: ICMP echo reply, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
```

br0 results

```
00:06:57.775050 52:54:00:a2:bd:48 > b0:00:b4:02:93:6e, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775940 b0:00:b4:02:93:6e > 52:54:00:a2:bd:48, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.202.7.4 > 10.202.7.128: ICMP echo reply, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
```

eno1 results

```
00:06:57.775074 52:54:00:a2:bd:48 > b0:00:b4:02:93:6e, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.202.7.128 > 10.202.7.4: ICMP echo request, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
00:06:57.775940 b0:00:b4:02:93:6e > 52:54:00:a2:bd:48, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.202.7.4 > 10.202.7.128: ICMP echo reply, id 27288, seq 1, length 64
```

The `775050` timestamp corresponds to `vnet5` and `br0`, the expected first "hop" (`vnet5` to `br0`).  The `775074` corresponds to `eno1` which is the expected second "hop" (`br0` to `eno1`).  I have no explanation for the repeat of the second `775050` entry because it is still a request.

The `775940` timestamp corresponds to `eno1` and `br0`, the expected first "hop" of the reply (`eno1` to `br0`).  The `775956` timestamp corresponds to `vnet5`, the expected second "hop" of the reply (`br0` to `vnet5`).  Again, I have no explanation for the repeat of the second `775940` entry because it is still a reply.

Final note, both "`Out`" entries refer to `br0` transmitting to an interface (`eno1` on outbound, `vnet5` on inbound).

If anyone has an explanation for the repeat of the two entries please respond.

Comment: Are you running `tcpdump` on the hypervisor or inside the guest? Also, is the second guest running on the same hypervisor? Are the two guests and/or the hypervisor in the same subnet?

Comment: tcpdump is being run on the hypervisor while the guest is pinging, the source, destination and hypervisor are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked in [the source code](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/master/print-sll.c#L142) of the `tcpdump`.

Meanings of the packet type field:

- **`In`** - packet addressed to host
- **`Out`** - outgoing packet
- **`B`** - broadcast
- **`M`** - multicast
- **`P`** - packet addressed to other host

#### Update

Duplicated packets in the `tcpdump` output caused by `-i any` option.

When a ethernet frame passed through linux bridge and you use `-i any` option of the tcpdump, you will see this frame several times. First time you see the frame on the input interface (`vnet5`), second time on the bridge interface itself (`br0`), and third time on the output interface (`eno1`). Seeing transit frames on the bridge interface is the side effect of implementation of ethernet bridging in the linux kernel.

Also, when a bridge interface have several ports (slave interfaces), in some cases you see copies of frames on every port, when an ethernet frame is flooded. It happens for broadcast, multicast and unknown unicast frames.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your duplication is caused by the `-i any` option you have passed.

When you do that you tcpdump will capture on every interface, and in the case of a router, or a bridge or something where a packet is being forwarded between interfaces it will return a copy of the packet for **every** interface that it hits.

I am not very familiar with KVM, but I believe if you have 2 VMs connected by a bridge interface you would have on virtual interface per VM, and the bridge interface.

Anyway, if you don't want duplication, restrict tcpdump to a single interface, by providing the name of a specific interface to the `-i` option. Though for some problems you may actually want all interfaces, and in that case you just have to understand that you are going to see duplication.